# How to store user profile returned by Oauth in database?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization

lets say I have a SQL database with 3 columns
username(unique),
email (unique ),
password .

A user sign up simply by filling up form with his name, email and password I store that into the database now when some other user signs up with the google (OAuth) and has the same username which is already stored into the database then what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the developer.

1. Try to check if username already exists before inserting. And If exists

a. Try adding random number/user id along with the username and store.

b. Try redirecting the user to a page and ask for a username(don't complete registration till the new username is received).

c. Create separate tables for normal registration and OAuth Registration.
And refer the corresponding tables based on user login procedure.